# Cannot GetResource image from Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin.forms, bitmap

Hi all id like to know what im doing wrong woth using getresource to load my image?, have tried all types of path strings but all return null image. Image file is 'Embedded Resource'

```
private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {

        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        Image image = new Image
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources.drawable.testimg.jpg")
        };
        SKBitmap _preloadedBitmap = ConvertToSkBitmap(image);

        canvas.Clear();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(_preloadedBitmap, 200, 200);
    }
```

[image: Folder Structure]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Views\testimg.jpg" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Properties\testimg.jpg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Does that even compile? ImageSource.FromResource("Resources.drawable.testimg.jpg") try instead: ImageSource.FromResource(R.drawable.testimg)

Comment: first, `FromResource` will by default look in the executing assembly (the shared project, not Android).  You either need to place the images in the shared assembly, or provide a reference to the Android assembly.  Second, embedded resource ids default to `Namespace.filename.ext`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#embedded-images

Comment: hI r.drawable.testimg does not compile, error on R. YEs the string version seems to comile no matter whatb string I input. And when you say put in the shared assembly, how do i do this? as the Views folder is in the shraed project already @Jason

Comment: the embedded resource needs to be in the shared assembly

Comment: @Jason im not sure im understanding correclty how to add this to the assemnbly and then reference it :( ive added code in shard project to show item it added, i moved it to properties

Comment: Literally just add the image to the shared project and mark it as an embedded resource.  The docs I linked to explain this in detail

Comment: @Jason have added the file to RECOmobile shared project, then marked the file as embedded resource, changed getResource( "testimg.jpg" ) but the bitmap still always says image is null

Comment: Again, please read the docs and pay attention to the naming convention for embedded resources.

Comment: @Jason have used all type of naming conventions the bitmap always shows as null. The docs specify Source = ImageSource.FromResource("RECOmobile.testimg.jpg", typeof(RecPODPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly) which doesnt work, (i used the page class as type of?)

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't in `ConvertToSkBitmap`?

Comment: @Jason im thinking that is the case as the 'Source' if the image is not null in debugger.. but thats annoying since i dont understand why that would be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string resourceID = "RECOmobile.testimg.jpg";
                Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
                {
                    bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
                }
```

This is the end solution that worked for me, I also had an error in 'ConvertToSkBitmap' soo removed method.